# OmNET++ dynamically check if NED module implements an interface

Tags: c++, omnet++

In an OmNET++ simulation, I need to dynamically create modules in C++ based on a string that is passed to the constructor. The string is parsed and then the modules (which already exist as a NED file) are created like this:

```
cModuleType* mwType = cModuleType::get(mwName);
cModule* middleware = mwType->create(mwName, this);
```

However, I would like to only create modules that implement a certain `moduleinterface`, which is also defined in a NED file, i.e. I only want to create modules defined as `simple MyModule like MyInterface {...}` and throw an exception for all others. Is there a way to check for this condition in OmNET++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether a simple module class implements `moduleinterface` named `MyInterface` using the following way:

```
cModuleType *mwType = cModuleType::get(mwName);
std::string desc = mwType->str();
const std::string interfaceName = "MyInterface";
if (desc.find(interfaceName) != std::string::npos) {
    EV << mwName << " implements " << interfaceName << endl;
    cModule* middleware = mwType->create(mwName, this);
    // ...
} else {
    EV << mwName << " does not implement " << interfaceName << endl;
}
```